# how to run a fuction in series NODEJS

Tags: node.js

I am using the async waterfall model to execute functions in sequence. However, within each function it does not execute statement in series. For instance below

```
var serviceconfig = loadCsv();
callback(null, serviceconfig);
```

I want the callback to only execute when the loadCsv() function returns the value but looks like it would continue the execution

```
apiRoutes.get('/api/:service/:subject', function(req, res) {

async.waterfall([
  function(callback){
    var serviceconfig = loadCsv();
    callback(null, serviceconfig);

  },
  function(serviceconfig, callback){
    console.log("serviceconfig final: " + serviceconfig);
    callback(null, 'd');
  },
  function(argd, callback){     

  }], function (err, result) {

  }
)


});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could, if it is possible for you, send the callback to the loadCsv, and let it handle it.

`var serviceconfig = loadCsv(callback);`

And then in loadCsv:

```
function loadCsv(callback) {
    // code
    callback(null, result);
}
```